# To compare date columns in grouped data

Tags: pandas, iteration

In the below dataframe,

```
       patient      admit       discharge     30d_admit
   0       a       2022-03-01   2022-03-01   2022-01-31
   1       a       2022-02-02   2022-02-02   2022-01-04
   2       a       2022-01-28   2022-01-28   2021-12-30
   3       b       2022-12-04   2022-12-04   2022-11-05
   4       c       2022-11-13   2022-11-13   2022-10-15
   5       c       2022-10-23   2022-10-23   2022-09-24
```

i want to check condition if any discharge date for patient 'a','b','c' lies between 30d_admit and admit date then counter should set high for eg:

```
         patient      admit     discharge  30d_admit     count
   0        a          2022-03-01 2022-03-01 2022-01-31     1
   1        a          2022-02-02 2022-02-02 2022-01-04     1
   2        a          2022-01-28 2022-01-28 2021-12-30     0
   3        b          2022-12-04 2022-12-04 2022-11-05     0
   4        c          2022-11-13 2022-11-13 2022-10-15     1
   5        c          2022-10-23 2022-10-23 2022-09-24     0
```

I want counts of discharge dates for particular admit for patient a,b,c that lies between
30d_admit and admit date

```
    for patient a  
                         admit        discharge     30d_admit    
     first check       2022-03-01 > 2022-03-01 > 2022-01-31   count=0
     second check      2022-03-01 > 2022-02-02 > 2022-01-31   count=1
     third check       2022-03-01 > 2022-01-28 > 2022-01-31   count=0
```

total count for admit 2022-03-01 = 1
similarly need to check for other admit dates in grouped data.

Kindly provide the solution to above problem

tried iterrows() on grouped data..kindly provide solution on how to use iterrows in grouped dataframe

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "patient": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c"],
        "admit": [
            "2022-03-01",
            "2022-02-02",
            "2022-01-28",
            "2022-12-04",
            "2022-11-13",
            "2022-10-23",
        ],
        "discharge": [
            "2022-03-01",
            "2022-02-02",
            "2022-01-28",
            "2022-12-04",
            "2022-11-13",
            "2022-10-23",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), and [Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```py
for col in ("admit", "discharge"):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format="%Y-%m-%d")


new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.assign(
            time_period=f"{time_period[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} "
            f"to {time_period[1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}",
            count=(df["discharge"] > time_period[0])
            & (df["discharge"] < time_period[1]),
        )
        .groupby(["time_period", "patient"])
        .agg({"count": "sum"})
        for time_period in [
            (admit_date - pd.Timedelta("30D"), admit_date)
            for admit_date in df["admit"].unique()
        ]
    ]
)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output

                                  count
time_period              patient       
2022-01-30 to 2022-03-01 a            1
                         b            0
                         c            0
2022-01-03 to 2022-02-02 a            1
                         b            0
                         c            0
2021-12-29 to 2022-01-28 a            0
                         b            0
                         c            0
2022-11-04 to 2022-12-04 a            0
                         b            0
                         c            1
2022-10-14 to 2022-11-13 a            0
                         b            0
                         c            1
2022-09-23 to 2022-10-23 a            0
                         b            0
                         c            0
```